# Ant performance Slow in Windows vs Linux

Tags: java, performance, ant, build, javac

We have a large system with multiple ant targets. The performance on Ant build (consists of javac,jarsigner,java tasks) is very slow (almost twice/thrice) in Windows vs Linux. Ant xmx is 512MB

Linux : Ubuntu 64 bit , 4 GB RAM, Intel Core2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz × 2 (desktop)

Windows : Windows 7 64 bit, 4 GB RAM, Intel i7 2.8GHz  (laptop)

Find below the comparison of time of few tasks (mostly javac) (in millisec) from Windows vs linux.

```
Windows Linux
117110  35033
32593   14300
10659   4107
9112    2704
8440    2464
3956    1844
3284    1635
2385    1091
1866    919
1722    752
1581    669
1529    579
1482    524
1468    478
1442    334
```

Are there any options to speed the performance in Windows?

Comment: what version of Ant are you using ?

Comment: I am using Ant 1.9.2 - latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further analysis, I saw that McAfee On-Access virus scan was running in my Windows 7 laptop. On disabling it, the build time reduced by half (50% improvement).

Comment: Nailed it for me.   Symantec Endpoint Protection has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause could be windows indexing service. In my case windows 10 it was windows defender and indexing service that consumed resources (mostly cpu).

In both cases you can exclude specific folders. you don't need to disable the services completely.